# GoogleJsonResponseException code: 403 : The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, youtube-data-api

I am trying to connect Youtube API to download their reports.

I am using GCS cloud and created a service account and security file, by using Java I tried to download reports.

Can anyone help me out on this

**Major Imports:**

```
import com.google.api.services.youtubereporting;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
```

**Error :**

```
GoogleJsonResponseException code: 403 : The caller does not have permission
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "The caller does not have permission",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Judging from the error it would seem that the account that is making the call does not have the proper permissions. I would suggest making sure that this account has the proper [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) to make the call.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. the permission has been added and able to make a call with server.